# Zend Framework 2 cannot create PostgreSQL db adapter

Tags: zend-framework2, php

I'm trying to setup a new web-application for learning purposes using the newest technologies: apache 2.4, PHP 5.4 and PostgreSQL 9.1

I've chosen to develop using Zend Framework 2.

In my main module I have defined this method:

```
public function getServiceConfiguration() {
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'adapter' => function ($sm) {
                $config = $sm->get('config');
                $adapter = new Adapter($config['db']);

                return $adapter;
            }
        ),
    );
}
```

$config['db'] is defined in my autoload/global.php, which contains:

```
return array(
    'db' => array(
        'driver' => 'PDO',
        'dsn' => 'pgsql:host=localhost;port=5436;user=root;password=myrootpwd',
    )
);
```

but when I try to call $serviceManager->get('adapter') I get an exception saying:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\Db\Adapter\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message 'The supplied or instantiated driver object does not implement Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\DriverInterface' in C:\Program Files\626Suite\application\library\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager.php on line 294
>
> Zend\Db\Adapter\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: The supplied or instantiated driver object does not implement Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\DriverInterface in C:\Program Files\626Suite\application\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter.php on line 80
>
> Call Stack:
> 0.0015     121600   1. {main}() C:\Program Files\626Suite\application\data\script\install.php:0
> 0.5699     936080   2. Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get(string(7), ???) C:\Program Files\626Suite\application\data\script\install.php:7
> 0.5700     936440   3. Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->create(array(2)) C:\Program Files\626Suite\application\library\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager.php:277
> 0.5701     936520   4. Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createServiceViaCallback(class Closure, string(7), string(7)) C:\Program Files\626Suite\application\library\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager.php:353
> 0.5701     936672   5. call_user_func(class Closure, class Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager, string(7), string(7)) C:\Program Files\626Suite\application\library\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager.php:543
> 0.5701     936696   6. Age\Module->Age{closure}(class Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager, string(7), string(7)) C:\Program Files\626Suite\application\library\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager.php:543
> 0.6047    1024184   7. Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter->__construct(class Zend\Config\Config, ???, ???) C:\Program Files\626Suite\application\module\Age\Module.php:43

EDIT:

I tried to modify the factory as:

```
public function getServiceConfiguration() {
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'adapter' => function ($sm) {
                $config = $sm->get('config');
                $PDO = new \PDO($config['db']['dsn']);
                $adapter = new Adapter($PDO);

                return $adapter;
            }
        ),
    );
}
```

And I first got an error saying that database "root" does not exists, but after changing my configuration to:

```
return array(
    'db' => array(
        'driver' => 'PDO',
        'dsn' => 'pgsql:host=localhost;port=5436;dbname=postgres;user=root;password=myrootpwd',
    )
);
```

I got back to getting the exception I described before.

Comment: By the way: I've never used PDO before, I'm switching to this directly from plain old mysql_query(), but AFAIK, after checking the PHP docs, the DSN string should be correct..

Comment: Yep, this is how its done http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-pgsql.connection.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I've been able to solve this problem too.

The solution was to update the currently used version of Zend Framework 2 from beta4 to the latest master downloaded directly from github.

I suppose there was a problem somewhere in Zend code itself, since now it is working properly without having changed anything in my code or in my settings.

Answer (score 5):

The following works for me:

/config/autoload/database.global.php

```
return array(
'db' => array(
    'driver'    => 'Pdo',
    'dsn'       => "pgsql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=mydb",
    'username'  => 'username',
    'password'  => 'mypass',
),
);
```

/module/Application/Module.php

```
public function getServiceConfiguration()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'db_adapter' =>  function($sm) {
                $config = $sm->get('Configuration');
                $dbAdapter = new \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter($config['db']);
                return $dbAdapter;
            }
        ),
    );
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE field=?";
$statement = $this->adapter->query($sql);
$res =  $statement->execute(array($var));
```

Comment: I see that you separated the DSN from the username and password, shouldn't those be placed in the DSN as well?

Anyway, I'll try your solution ASAP.